# How to remove a "door" in solaris

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, ipc

I have a file of type "door" in solaris 10 (that is a means of interprocess communication). It is somehow left over and I would like to get rid of it. I can not just remove it with rm ...

```
ls -l
total 0
Dr--r--r--   1 root     root           0 Oct 12  2012 name_service_door
# rm name_service_door 
rm: name_service_door not removed: Device busy
# lsof name_service_door
```

Obviously some process is still using it. However, lsof does not display anything. From a "ps -elf" is is also not clear who is using this. How can I get rid of this file?

Update: I rebootet the server, which of course killed all processes and thus released the file. I could then remove it. But still, I would be interested in knowing how to do this without rebooting (in production environments, that is not allways an option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a mount inside a chroot, so after unmounting it, I could remove it.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what set or installed the file. As root run this command.

```
pkgchk -l -p /files
```

- tells you what packages where used to create the file you give in the command.

Example

```
pkgchk -l -p *path to file*/name_service_door
```

This will not work, if the file was not added with a package. For example you installed it using a tar file.

If the file was installed via a package then you can remove the package and this will remove the file.

As root

```
pkgrm packagename
```

You ac also stop or restart the service with the svcadm command.

As root

> svcadm [enable|disable|restart|refresh] service

I hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunatly, the file did not come directly from a package, but was created with a script wich came from a package (which I am building). So the above command does not really help (I tried it).

Comment: Sorry that it didn't help